# How to dynamically create bindings

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to create a dynamic view model from data already in my dom . The idea is that I would like to introduce Knockout into my page without starting over. I have an unordered list that contain my data and I want to create my viewmodel from.

for example:

```
<ul>
  <li id="1">name1 <span data-bind="text:nbClicked"></span></li>
  <li id="2">name2 <span data-bind="text:nbClicked"></span></li>
</ul>
```

My problem is that the html is generated on the server side and I want to handle events with KO . Is there a way to construct dynamically a context for each elements of my list ?

Comment: This question is unclear (and your HTML is invalid). Please explain with a complete example what you have and what behavior you expect.

Comment: Are you saying you can't change the HTML in the back-end? Not sure KO can handle those situations

Comment: A "context for each elements of my list"? Do you mean each `<li>` will have a different viewmodel? What is this dynamically generated viewmodel going to *do*? You can't write very many interactions without knowing what properties you are working with.

Comment: @Tyrsius: Exactly each item of my list should have its own view model and the nbClicked property should own the number of click each item has been clicked.

Comment: @Dave that sounds like each item has the same viewmodel (in the sense that a viewmodel is a class, not an instance). If they are different viewmodels, what is different about them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a bit confused by exactly what you're trying to do, but you can apply separate view models for individual DOM elements.  The `ko.applyBindings` takes as a separate parameter a specific node:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    nbClicked: 'hello 1'
}, document.getElementById('1'));

ko.applyBindings({
    nbClicked: 'hello 2'
}, document.getElementById('2'));
```